# Query-Regarding-Gnutls-Build

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-14.04, gnutls

I am asked to develop a transport client that use gnutls (I am using 3.4.1).

Also I want to simulate more number of such tls clients .

In my application each client is a separate process.

My each process dynamically links with the gmp,nettle and gnutls libs.

Without tls I am able to easily simulate more than 10k connections(with tcp/udp) in my machine(of 8 gb RAM).

But with tls in place I am not able to simulate more than 800 connections.
Memory is getting dried up, and is a big concern for me.

I ran with Valgrind memory check tool and I see zero errors and zero warnings.

Can anyone please help me what care I should take while building the gnutls, so that it is optimized and can be made best possible use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of callgrind to profile and see if any api in gnutls is called repeatedly. Though [this](http://blog.josefsson.org/category/programming/gnutls/) looks an old one, but you can find how callgrind was used to find the issue.

Comment: You can look at gnutls_sec_param_to_pk_bits and  gnutls_dh_params_generate2. In gnutls_dh_params_generate2, you provide bits as second argument. Higher the bits value, it takes more time and memory. So while calculating bits using gnutls_sec_param_to_pk_bits api, make sure bits value is low. You should do this only if you want lower security.